# Как сделать разметку экрана, чтобы крайние элементы подстраивались под средний?

Tags: java, android

Есть:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCntr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.6"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Надо программно менять высоту ivCntr, но так чтобы он оставался в центре, а ivL и ivR меняли размер соответственно подстраиваясь . Как это сделать?

В принципе меня бы устроило и так, если бы я понял как менять программно

```
layout_weight
```

Пока я понял только как менять высоту или ширину программно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В принципе меня бы устроило если бы я понял как менять программно `layout_weight`

Изменить программно атрибут [`layout_weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight) можно установив новые [`LinearLayout.LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) методом [`setLayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)).

[Один из конструкторов](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#LinearLayout.LayoutParams(int,%20int,%20float)) класса `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` принимает три аргумента: `ширину`, `высоту`, и `layout_weight`. В качестве ширины и высоты можно передать, например, [`MATCH_PARENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT) или [`WRAP_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#WRAP_CONTENT):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    2.0f // новый layout_weight
);
объект_view.setLayoutParams(params);
```